# Showing validation errors in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, validation-rule

In Salesforce1, the validation rule is preventing the record from being saved but the error message is not shown, making it difficult for the user to fix the error. Is there a way to show the error message?

Comment: Scott, welcome to SFSE! I encourage you to check the [ask] page. In order to help you better, we need a lot more information, starting with some snippets of code that will let us see the problem you're describing.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the error location to be at the top of the page rather the beside the field fixes this.